# Avalonia UserControl checking if it is visible before before acting on a timer

Tags: c#, avaloniaui, avalonia

I have a loading overlay (with the View inheriting from `UserControl` and the ViewModel from `ViewModelBase`) that I display over the current window by putting using a `<Grid>` and having the regular controls in a `<StackPanel>` and then the loading screen after it in a `<Border>`, binding the `<Border>`'s `IsVisible` property to control the display of the overlay.

```
<Window ...>
    <Grid>
        <StackPanel>
            <!-- Window controls here -->
        </StackPanel>
        <Border Background="#40000000" 
                IsVisible="{Binding IsLoading}">
            <views:LoadingScreenView />
        </Border>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

In the `LoadingScreenViewModel` I use an `HttpClient` to download a JSON file to parse and display on the loading overlay.

It is refreshed in the `LoadingScreenViewModel` every 10 seconds by using a timer

```
private IObservable<long> timer = Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10),
                                    Scheduler.Default);
```

and then subscribing to it in the ViewModel's constructor

```
    public LoadingScreenViewModel()
    {
        LoadingText = "Loading...";

        timer.Subscribe(async _ =>
        {
            var json = await _httpClient.GetStringAsync(...);
            var dict = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, string>>(json);
            LoadingText = dict["result"];
        });
    }
```

The problem is that since I include the `LoadingScreenView` in the window, this timer is firing every ten second, even when the loading overlay isn't displayed.

Is there any way to check if the overlay itself is visible during that `Subscribe()`, passing the IsLoading property to the `LoadingScreenViewModel`, or creating and destroying the View every time it is used?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to achieve this by adding a `bool isVisible` property to the `LoadingScreenViewModel`, having the view inherit from `ReactiveUserControl<LoadingScreenViewModel>`, and per the discussion at https://github.com/AvaloniaUI/Avalonia/discussions/7876 I achieved this in code-behind by subscribing to changes in the view's TransformedBounds property and determining if the view is visible based on if TransformedBounds is null or not.

```
public LoadingScreenView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.WhenAnyValue(v => v.TransformedBounds)
            .Subscribe(x => ViewModel.isVisible = x is not null);
    }
```